# How to move rows from one workbook to another (no select)

Tags: excel, vba

My goal is to take an excel document with variable row size, copy it and then paste it onto the bottom row of a new document.

Longer story, I need to take monthly sales reports and stack them into a larger excel file. Each month we make a variable number of sales. I need to aggregate all of these months together so we can process them.

I have some code that I thought worked below. It was able to move variable rows within different work sheets, but could not do the same for different work books.

```
Private Sub MoveRowToEndOfTable()
Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows,SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
Sheets(1).Range("A2:A" & LastRow, "G2:G" & LastRow).Copy
Workbooks("BRN report Aggregator.xlsx").Worksheets("New shares EOM").Range("a6000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Cells.Insert
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. 

It makes it so the first time I run the code it copies one row, then the next time it copies two rows, then four rows ect. ect.

Comment: Wait now it works? Maybe I just wasn't talking nice to it. And now it doesn't work again and has the error I described.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that your workbook is closed, check it before paste values (if workbook is closed ~> open it) :

```
Private Sub MoveRowToEndOfTable()
   Dim LastRow As Long
   LastRow = Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
   Sheets(1).Range("A2:A" & LastRow, "G2:G" & LastRow).Copy
   Dim wb As Workbook, wb_target As Workbook
   'check if workbook is open already
   For Each wb In Workbooks
       If wb.Name = "BRN report Aggregator.xlsx" Then
           Set wb_target = Workbooks("BRN report Aggregator.xlsx")
               Exit For
       End If
   Next wb
   'if not then open it
   If wb_target Is Nothing Then
       Set wb = Workbooks.Open("Path_to_file/BRN report Aggregator.xlsx")
   End If
   wb.Worksheets("New shares EOM").Range("a6000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll 'or xlPasteValues  --depends on your needs
   wb.Close True 'save and close if required
End Sub
```

Comment: No, Sadly that is not it. I have separate subs for opening and closing the document in questions, though your code is much cleaner then mine and I will be using it. It has something to do with the range, it appears as through what I have in the BRN report Aggregator effects what the code copies.

Comment: I've tried, if problem with the range then I think problem can be with reference to workbooks and worksheets ...

Comment: Alright, it looks like it works so, I will set this to solved. Thank you for your help.